# Export SQL Server database as .mdf without take it offline

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Does somebody know the a way to export a SQL Server database as `.mdf` file without taking it offline or detaching?

I need to export it with the actual tables and data but without stopping the SQL Server service or so...

Comment: Tag the dbms you are using! (Product specific problem.)

Comment: Sorry Sir i dont understand

Comment: Either you have to **detach** the `.mdf` file, or then you need to create a **backup** (which gives you a `.bak` file which you can restore elsewhere). A SQL Server backup also contains **all the database objects** (tables, view, stored procedures and functions) and **all the data**

Comment: I don't want to use it as backup, i need to attach it to a .net programm, which doesn't work with .bak files

Comment: @JulPod, mission completed. sql-server tag is correct since this is a MS SQL Server problem, and has nothing to do with the SQL language (as specified by ISO/ANSI.)

Comment: @jarlh, o sorry, bit sleepy today :D

Comment: Take a backup, restore it somewhere else, and then detach from there.

Comment: Is this possible also when there are others just working on that db ?

Comment: Its more like a question for a DBA. You should post it in http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Take backup and restore in the destination.

Comment: Hello Sir, 

is this also possible when others are current working on that database, because thats the main reason i dont use this method